# Get Facebook email and save to Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

The below code adds the parse login and signup forms. But when I use the Facebook fields, it logs in the user but it does not update the email fields.

Is there a way I can get the email field updated?

```
func showLogInPage() {
    var loginViewController = PFLogInViewController()
    loginViewController.delegate = self
    loginViewController.fields = (PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.Facebook)
    var signupViewController = PFSignUpViewController()
    signupViewController.delegate = self
    loginViewController.signUpController = signupViewController
    self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the `PFLogInViewControllerDelegate` there is a callback which is triggered when logging in with Facebook called `logInViewController:didLogInUser`. In here you can retrieve the email from the Facebook SDK and store it in the `PFUser`. I've made a small example here:

```
// MARK: - PFLogInViewControllerDelegate

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) {
    updatePFUserEmail()
}

func updatePFUserEmail() {
    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) in
            if (error != nil) { return }
            if let user = result as? NSDictionary {
                if let email = user.objectForKey("email") as? String {
                    PFUser.currentUser()?.email = email
                    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
                }
                else {
                    PFUser.currentUser()?.email = ""
                    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

Missing the FB permission settings

---

You need to specify the Facebook permission in your `showLogInPage` to read the user's email. You can do this in the following way:

```
loginViewController.facebookPermissions = ["email"]
```

Comment: tried the code above, the email is returned as "nil"

Comment: I've updated the answer specifying how to add the facebook permission for the email

Answer (score 0):

For those updating to Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0, this is the syntax:

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) 
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

```
if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
    self.loginViewController.fields = 
    [PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword, 
    PFLogInFields.LogInButton, 
    PFLogInFields.SignUpButton, 
    PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten, 
    PFLogInFields.DismissButton, 
    PFLogInFields.Twitter, 
    PFLogInFields.Facebook]

    self.loginViewController.delegate = self
    self.signupViewController.delegate = self

    self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}